# Sync Framework 2.1 Local Cache as SQL Server Possible?

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

Could someone please help me with whether it's possible to use a full blown SQL Server as Local Database Cache instead of CE?

The reason being CE has 4GB limit. CE is not an option for us as our database records will grow significantly within few months.

Any alternative solution will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're referring to the Local Database Cache project item in Visual Studio, the answer is no. Only Sql Compact (SqlCeClientSyncProvider) is supported by that wizard. You can however handcode your own provider and the sync code without using the wizard.

or you can just use the SqlSyncProvider (can be used against Sql Express, Sql Server, Sql Azure).

see: [Synchronizing SQL Server and SQL Express](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928676%28SQL.110%29.aspx)